# C# render panel programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class `MyUserControl` containing some plots that normally I add to a form for visualization.

However, I have a feature that requires me to write a `MyUserControl` object to an image file, but I only seem to see white in the image.

My code is as follows:

```
MyUserControl uc = new MyUserControl();
uc.loadData();
int width = uc.Size.Width;
int height = uc.Size.Height;
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
uc.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
bm.Save(@"C:\path\to\file.bmp");
```

What do I need to do to "trick" my `MyUserControl` into thinking its already been added to a panel for rendering, but have it render directly into a file instead?

Comment: What class and interfaces does MyUserControl inherit from?

Comment: Maybe try calling uc.OnPaint(null) before calling bm.Save()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/rendering-a-windows-forms-control

Comment: DrawToBitmap will draw whatever you draw in the Paint event.

Comment: The problem is I'm not overriding OnPaint. Instead I have a ZedGraph control that I've added to a sub-panel as well as two other Telerik RadPanels which I've attached paint events to. Is it possible to refactor all of this into OnPaint() without losing the custom interactivity on the plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `SaveToBitmap()` method to your control. So you can call the protected `OnPaint()` method.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
   ...
  public void SaveToBitmap(string filePath)
  {
    using(Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
      var bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height, g);
      using(Graphics gBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
      {
        PaintEventArgs e = new PaintEventArgs(gBmp, this.ClientRectangle);
        this.OnPaint(e);        
      }
      bmp.Save(filePath);        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just writes a completely black 100x200 px image.